# How to plot an image using PIL or Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I am trying to plot an image in python using either PIL or Matplotlib. I have tried both

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

and

```
from PIL import Image
```

But I get the same error:
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL'

I have updated pillow and matplotlib packages but no success

Answer (score 0):

You can read the image using open cv and then plot it using matplotlib.

```
img_name = cv2.imread("image.jpeg")
plt.imshow(img_name)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks @Rabi but the problem is with import of matplotlib. The system gives me the error when I want to import matplotlib or pillow

Comment: Please appreciate the answer , If you like it.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when folk use `python` and `pip` from different packages, distributions or versions. I mean you install a package with `pip` into one package/distribution/version and then try and use it from a different package/distribution/version of Python.

---

So, if you normally start Python using:

```
python
```

then run:

```
type python
```

Whereas if you normally start Python using:

```
python3
```

then run:

```
type python3
```

On my machine I get:

```
type python3
python3 is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3
```

so now I know which Python I am using.

---

Now you need to see which `pip` you are using. So, if you normally start `pip` with:

```
pip
```

then run:

```
type pip
```

Whereas if you normally start `pip` with:

```
pip3
```

then run:

```
type pip3
```

On my machine I get:

```
type pip3
pip3 is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/pip3
```

---

So now you can see that my `pip3` is installing packages for `python3` exactly where it can find them.